# How to create multi module project in Intellij?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

Please bear with me as Iam new to Intellij. How to make multi module project using IntelliJ wizard? Please show some link or video.

Please help. A billion thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create multi-module Maven project - first create a new Maven project

1. File | New | Project and select **Maven** type.

Then create additional Maven modules using

2. File | New | **Module**, then select **Maven**.

See also [Add a new Maven module to an existing project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#maven_add_module).

Answer (score 0):

You can go File->New->Module... or File->New->Module from Existing Sources...